# Windows script: text manipulation for text strings

Tags: windows, text, sed, cmd, gawk

need big help again

File1:

```
\\server2\share1,\\serverdfs\dfs\test2
\\server1\anothershare,\\serverdfs\dfs\test1
```

File2:

```
\\server2\share1,/fs7/server1/share1
\\server1\anothershare,/fs1/serverx/share1
\\server4\newshare,/fs7/server1/share1
```

Script:

```
@ECHO OFF 
DEL file3 2 > nul 
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%i IN (file1.txt) DO ( 
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%a IN (file2.txt) DO ( 
   IF /i "%%i"=="%%a" >>file3 ECHO %%i,%%j,%%b>file3.txt
  ) 
)
```

The output is something like this:

```
\\server2\share1,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test2,/fs7/server1/share1  
\\server1\anothershare,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test1,/fs1/serverx/share1
```

The script will search for matches (first field = anything before the comma) between both files (file1.txt & file2.txt).

The problem is for example with `\\server4\newshare` which is only present on file2.txt.

In this case both of these lines have the same second field:

```
\\server2\share1,/fs7/server1/share1
\\server4\newshare,/fs7/server1/share1
```

Can you think of anything in order to show an output similar to this:

```
\\server2\share1,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test2,/fs7/server1/share1  
\\server1\anothershare,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test1,/fs1/serverx/share1
```

`only_at_file2.txt, \\server4\newshare,/fs7/server1/share1 same path as \\server2\share1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
}

FNR==NR {
   array[$1]=$2
   next
}

{
   if ($1 in array) { 
      print $1, "\\"array[$1], $2
   }

   else {
      if ($2 in values) {
         print "only_at_" FILENAME ", " $0 " same path as " values[$2]
      }
      else {
         print "only_at_" FILENAME ", " $0 " no path found"
      }
   }
   values[$2]=$1
}
```

Results:

```
\\server2\share1,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test2,/fs7/server1/share1
\\server1\anothershare,\\\serverdfs\dfs\test1,/fs1/serverx/share1
only_at_file2.txt, \\server4\newshare,/fs7/server1/share1 same path as \\server2\share1
```

---

If there are duplicate paths, this will show the last path found in `file2.txt` (i.e. `values[$2]=$1` will override previous paths). For example, if now another server with a path of `/fs7/server1/share1` is found in `file2.txt`, the output server will be `\\server4\newshare`